# Overpy.result object parsing issues

Tags: python, openstreetmap

I am trying to use osm data for a project and cannot figure out how to use the data that is returned by the overpy api.

```
api = overpy.Overpass()
test = api.query("""area[name="New York"];relation[route="subway"](area);out;""")
test1 = test.get_relations()
```

The .get_relations() returns information but I need the data in an object I can import as a python array or a json object. I can see the output in overpass turbo as the json dictionary that I want. Any help would be appreciated.
http://overpass-turbo.eu/ This is the website to test the query.

Answer (score 2):

The standard [output format](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_QL#Output_Format_.28out:.29) of [Overpass API](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API) is XML. If you want to request JSON output then you need to add `[out:json]`:

```
[out:json];area[name="New York"];relation[route="subway"](area);out;
```

Comment: It seems like the overpy package handles the response in either JSON or xml. I just ended up using the .relations tag from the overpy package